# Не работает звук/UnityEvent

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Создал публичный `UnityEvent`, подписал на него `AudioSource.Play()` раньше звук работал, потом, неизвестно от чего, но перестал. Причем именно в скомпилированном проекте под Android, в GameMode все работает. Искал в интернете часа 2-3 — ноль. Пробовал воспроизводить звук через `PlayOneShot()`, результат не изменился. Звук в скомпилированном проекте работает, для проверки поставил флажок на Play on Awake и звук был. Просто `UnityEvent` не хочет вызывать `Play()`. Настройки Audio проверял. Звуком из кода никак не управляю. Ивент прекрасно работает все подписчики отрабатывают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему что-то типо костылем.
Почему-то это работает...

```
private AudioSource _audioSource;

private void Awake()
{
    _audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

public void Play(AudioClip audioClip)
{
    _audioSource.PlayOneShot(audioClip);
}
```